# Is there tutorial available for PostGIS setup in ArcSDE 10.1 geodatabase on Linux?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, linux

Is there any tutorial for Set up PostGIS in an ArcSDE 10.1 geodatabase on Linux?

There is one in [tutorial arcgis 9](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35488) for ArcGIS version 9, but I couldn't find any for ArcGIS 10.1.